# ember-pouch: does not load hasMany relationship when the belongsTo side is polymorphic

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, couchdb, pouchdb, relational-pouch

I have an ember-data app that uses the [ember-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/ember-pouch) adapter for local & remote storage.

I am unable to load `hasMany` relationships when the `belongsTo` side is polymorphic. I've played with `async: true/false` and `donstsave: true/false` options on the `hasMany` side, to no avail.

#### The setup:

- `post` can have many `comments`.
- `comment` can have many `comments`.
- `comment` belongs to `commentable`.

```js
// app/models/post.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { Model } from 'ember-pouch';

export default Model.extend({
    DS.hasMany('comment', { inverse: 'commentable' });
});

// app/models/comment.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { Model } from 'ember-pouch';

export default Model.extend({
    DS.belongsTo('commentable', { polymorphic: true });
    DS.hasMany('comment', { inverse: 'commentable' });
});
```

#### The Problem

Calling `post.get('comments')` loads nothing. If comments are loaded into the store separately, however, then `post` is able to correctly render comments:

```
// In the console (being mindful that `post.get('comments')` returns a promise)

const post = store.findRecord('post', '123');
post.get('comments').get('length'); // => 0

store.findAll('comment');
post.get('comments').get('length'); // => 12
```

Comment: Did you get any solutions for this?

Comment: I didn't. I tabled the project shortly afterward and never resolved it. I'd love to hear if you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me during an experiment (although I was heavily modifying ember-pouch within the adapter) was using `post.get('comments').content.length` but don't ask me why this is so and if it is supposed to be that way ...

EDIT:
It seems the problem is that the data is not loaded at that time. So probably something like `post.get('comments').then(function() {this.debug(post.get('comments').length}))` will work.